# Backing Up a Bootcamped MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, partitioning, boot-camp, ios, osx-el-capitan

I'm in a situation right now where budget is tight, and I've got one laptop at my disposal it's a late 2015 MacBook Pro, it's got a 256GB SSD. I'm not really a huge fan of OSX as I'm a Windows/C# developer. So I wanted to dual boot at first between OSX and Windows 10 Pro via Bootcamp, and that's my current configuration. On Disk Manager in Windows it shows:

Apple Partitions:
200MB EFI System Partition - Type: Basic

131.66GB Primary Partition - Type: Basic

620MB Primary Partition - Type: Basic

Then Windows Partitions:

C: BOOTCAMP: 93.85GB NTFS (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition)

D: 7.45GB NTFS (Primary Partition)

What I want to do is backup the OSX Images as they are, delete the OSX partitions, get rid of the D: partition, then move C: partition up to the front of the drive and then expand it. The Bootcamp bootloader I guess would need to know the new location of the partition on the drive.

Is what I want possible or feasible?

Comment: It's possible - but not for free. You'd also need a 2nd drive for safety, it's not something I'd attempt without a solid backup. [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) can backup/restore/move/resize/fix boot loaders etc etc on HFS+ & NTFS/GUID/MBR/Bootcamp hybrids. I just this morning backed up a drive with HFS & BC partitions, wiped the drive & reassembled it from scratch. It boots :)

Comment: @Tetsujin Can Paragon run from a bootable USB instead of inside an OSX session? What I'd like to do is wipe the OSX partition completely, then move the Windows partition to the front of the drive and expand it to the full capacity of the drive. 

I want to keep the 200MB EFI partition assuming that is where Bootcamp and the Hard Disk Recovery is stored so that in case I decide later to put OSX back on I can.

Comment: Yes, it can make its own recovery USB, but it uses the regular Recovery partition to make it initially. Assuming you don't need the macOS partition at all, I would then keep the EFI & Recovery partitions, 250 & 650 MB respectively; & also keep the Paragon USB safe, so you can more easily revert at any time.